# PHP: How can I cache a page using output buffer?

Tags: php, mysql, output-buffering

I'm trying to cache a page that gets/processes data from very slow API's - so I can load it quickly to the user. But for some reason the output buffer is empty?

```
<?php

ob_start();

// here I have php scripting accessing api's for information

?>


// Here I have HTML content with some php conditions and echos to filter and display the gathered information

// then I try to save the buffered page to the database:

<?php

//connect to database
$page = ob_get_contents();

mysql_query("UPDATE `pages` SET `page_cache` = '" . $page . "' WHERE `page_id` = '" . $page_id . "'");

?>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the output if you `var_dump($page)` instead of issuing a query?

Comment: You should call `ob_end_clean()` at the end of working with output buffer. Try to comment `ob_start()` - do you see any output?

Comment: @watcher hi watcher var_dump($page) has no output :S

Comment: hi jan what do you mean by comment it?

Comment: What Jan means is what do you see if you don't buffer anything, but just display the page.

Comment: the page displays fine with or without the buffer - could the issue be to do with the very slow API / processing of the large array returned? it takes about 15-20 seconds to make the page!

Comment: Your API may have another `ob_start(); ... ob_end_clean();` or something???

Comment: its just facebook and twitter api and stuff like that

Comment: Hi sorry var_dump($page) gets bool(false) does that make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you making sure your $page contains only database-safe characters?

What happens if the output contains a single `'` for example?

Comment: I try to echo or print_r $page before it gets to the database bit and it prints nothing

Comment: Hmm okay, so it doesn't seem to be a database query error. (Although you **do** need to sort that too)

Comment: cool thanks for the heads up for when I hopefully get this working :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to let MySQL encode that $page variable:

```
mysql_query(sprintf(
    "UPDATE `pages` SET `page_cache`='%s' WHERE `page_id`=%s",
    mysql_real_escape_string( $page ),
    intval( $page_id )  // assuming it's an int
));
```

Comment: @Joe, this is basically what I was talking about to keep your inserts clean :)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether output buffering is on in your /etc/php.ini:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php

Also, do an:

```
<?php echo ob_get_contents(); ?>
```

If it prints FALSE, then output buffering may not be enabled: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php